# Creating a presentation mode, like chromium

Tags: objective-c, fullscreen, toolbar

I am wondering if it's possible to **easily** make something like Chrome/ium's "Presentation Mode" on OS X [(see here)](http://www.exhume.us/presentation.gif). I made sure to look at Chromium's code, but I can't seem to de-managle it. It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: so... making it [full screen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html)? Also, what have you tried already? What has googling this question resulted in? This is a very broad question that you may not get a response to.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for making the question so broad. In Chrome or Chromium, they have a presentation mode, where it hides the toolbar, along with the menubar. I already have a fullscreen mode, but the toolbar remains in the view (if that makes any sense)